# Can I use the area above my garage for an extra room?

Tags: ceiling, joists, support

I want to use a 8 x 20 space above garage for an extra room (Load Bearing). It has two 2 x 10’s sister’d together spanning of 20 feet and 16 inches apart with no center support.

Can I make this set up into a room as described? What will be the path I need to take to make a (load Bearing) room. Will the set up I have meet the load requirements?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, you'll have to contact an engineer. Only an engineer will be able to tell you if the structure is adequate, and/or what you have to do to make it so.

If this is going to be a habitable room, you'll have to make sure it meets all the building requirements in your area. So you might have more to be concerned with, than just the floor.